# convert publickey to integer

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5

how will i convert the following public key to integer.

these are the RSAKeyValue:

**Modulus:**         *yf4I7PVef43rZ2NdPFA5FQFb/y/k/5Awqrwc+/VDUimthRg4C5K2P6EUhU5n2m4HUiz102LIuwsYDYuyHwG3VUbAb4zjqxiOwrSpsHfCvgOdLsb4DBrXFFGp5kMtoZrDzl84tnDlyYgy8v3o5Qp2eeQgDaau2PhYUxoco6IArHU=*

**Exponent:***AQAB*

i want to do this bcoz i want to take its xor with another integer value...

plz help here...

thnx...

Answer (score -1):

Without going into why you'd want to do this in the first place; if you want to XOR the modulus with another, there is no need to represent it as a big integer first. You can use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get an array of bytes, and XOR those byte for byte.

```
string firstModulus = "yf4I7 ...etc... HU=";
string secondModulus = "...";

byte[] m1 = Convert.FromBase64String(firstModulus);
byte[] m2 = Convert.FromBase64String(secondModulus);

byte[] xor = new byte[m1.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < m1.Length; i++)
    xor[i] = (byte)(m1[i] ^ m2[i % m2.Length]);

string xorString = Convert.ToBase64String(xor);
```

Edit: I've updated the code to allow m2 to be shorter than the m1 array. The array m2 can be filled from any source. In this example I use a second base64 string, but if you use a regular integer, you can use [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes%28VS.90%29.aspx) to convert it to a byte array.

For the record, .NET 3.5 does not have a built-in integer class that is big enough to hold the entire modulus. The whole reason that RSA works is because they are *very* large numbers. .NET 4 has [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx), but you don't need it here.

Comment: The OP makes no reference to having a second modulus.

Comment: No, but he mentioned some other integer value. This is just an example.